# Replace Default Menu Flyout with costum one in RichEditBox in uwp

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I wanted to replace the Default Menu Flyout with my custom Menu Flyout but below code is not working, still the default context menu is showing instead of custom one

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        RichEditBox box1;
        MenuFlyout myContextMenu;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            box1 = new RichEditBox()
            {
                Width = 500,
                Height = 30,
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
            };

            myContextMenu = new MenuFlyout();
            MenuFlyoutItem cutMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            cutMenuItem.Text = "Cut";
            myContextMenu.Items.Add(cutMenuItem);

            MenuFlyoutItem copyMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            copyMenuItem.Text = "Copy";
            myContextMenu.Items.Add(copyMenuItem);

            MenuFlyoutItem pasteMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            pasteMenuItem.Text = "Paste";
            myContextMenu.Items.Add(pasteMenuItem);

            MenuFlyoutItem selectAllMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            selectAllMenuItem.Text = "Select All";
            myContextMenu.Items.Add(selectAllMenuItem);

            box1.ContextFlyout = myContextMenu;

            Content = box1;
        }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I pasted your code in an empty project and everything works as expected.

Comment: @FrozenAssassine But if u select few characters from the RichEditBox u will be getting default context menu instead of myContextMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as you mentioned in the comments, it only happens when you select something:

There are two types of flyouts in a RichEditBox, first the default flyout and second the selection flyout. Here is the code to change both

```
box1.SelectionFlyout = box1.ContextFlyout = myContextMenu;
```